# Captcha not showing up Codeigniter & Tank_Auth

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha, tankauth

I use Tank_Auth for registration in my codeigniter app.
I enabled Captcha Registration but it is not showing.

I chmodded my folder to 777 and the path is right so it should show up.

My Tank_auth.php config file:

```
$config['captcha_path'] = './application/captcha/';
$config['captcha_fonts_path'] = './application/captcha/fonts/5.ttf';
$config['captcha_width'] = 200;
$config['captcha_height'] = 50;
$config['captcha_font_size'] = 14;
$config['captcha_grid'] = FALSE;
$config['captcha_expire'] = 180;
$config['captcha_case_sensitive'] = TRUE;
```

I have an .htacces file, so maybe that could be the problem.

My captcha folder is stored at `httpdocs/application/captcha`
my fonts are at `httpdocs/application/captcha/fonts/`

It show's me this:
[image: registration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$config['captcha_path'] = './application/captcha/';
```

change to this:

```
$config['captcha_path'] = './PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGES_FOLDER/captcha/';
```

Make sure you have a folder named `captcha` in your images folder of course with proper permissions. The CAPTCHA path is where the generated image is served to the browser. Files in the `./application` folder are not publicly accessible and thus can not serve the images. You need to make sure that the CAPTCHA location is outside of `./application` but still in the webroot. Usually the folder is `./assets` but you may be using a different location for your images, whatever it is use it.

Comment: allright thank you. i have an assets folder so i will put it in there :)